# Not able to crawl the correct data

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping

I want to crawl the current temp of Delhi from the below url. I am working with MEAN stack. I don't know about jQuery much. At times I get error:

```
{ [Error: socket hang up] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

And sometimes I get the whole string of temperatures of the week. How to get that temperature? Help me

```
 api.get('/scrape', function (req, res) {



        url = "http://www.timeanddate.com/weather/india/new-delhi";
        request(url,function(error,response,html) {
            if (!error) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(html);
                var title, release, rating;
                var json = {title: "", release: "", rating: ""};
                $('.').filter(function () {
                    var data = $(this);
                    title = data.children().first().text();
                    release = data.children().last().children().text();
                    json.title = title;
                    json.release = release;
                });

                console.log('before');

                var data=$('div.rows').find('span');

                console.log(data.text());

                console.log('after');
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(error);
            }

        });

    });
```

Comment: How often does this request get sent? you may want to send it on a regular interval (once every 5 minutes?) and store the result, then respond with the stored result instead of scraping every time it is needed. (there's also probably a webservice you could use for this instead of scraping...)

Comment: It gets sent when the person reloads a page in which we want the temp.

Comment: and, is that once per hour? 200 times per minute?

Comment: Requesting it on an interval will allow you to mitigate network errors by simply returning the last successful value until the another request is successful to update the value.

Comment: Why not using an api like: https://developer.forecast.io

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('before');
console.log($('.current-tem').find('span').html().substr(0,5));
```

You are most likely getting the occasional ECONNRESET because their site is slow...

Comment: How to know whether a site is slow or not. I mean which site to choose then to crawl the current temp.

Comment: @RayOfHope If you're scraping someone else's site, there's always going to be a chance that you'll get a network error.

Comment: Set the Request timeout option to a large value (say 600 seconds).  This may help...

Comment: How to do this? Do I have to set in this api?

Comment: request({url:url,timeout:600},function(error,response,html))

Answer (score 0):

As I was saying always better use an api like [forecast.io](http://developer.forecast.io) more reliable than web scraping.

Comment: I am getting that this method has issues with it. But I need to scrap the temp of New Delhi on our website within 3 hours and submit it. Can you please help me out a way so that I can make changes in my api.